# c - print each line in stdin

Tags: c, stdin

I want `echo "1 2\n h a\n hello" | ./a.out` to give me:

```
1 2
h a
hello
```

Here is my current code, which prints the entire input `1 2\n h a\n hello` on one line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char buffer[256];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Then, the input should be `1 2\n h a\n hello`. Convert the string `\n ` to newline by yourself.

Comment: Note that there'll be a blank at the start of the second and third lines because you've put a blank after the newline in the echoed string — once you sort out how to echo the data with `\n` expanded to a newline.  You could use `printf "%s\n" "1 2" "h a" "hello" | a.out` as another way to get the result you want.  (Also note that you could do a lot of your own debugging by simply observing the output from `echo "1 2\n h a\n hello"` without piping it to your program.  A standard debugging technique is to ensure that your program is seeing the data you expect it to see.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, echo doesn't convert escape sequences, so `"\n"` is literally getting sent to your file. See below:

```
$ echo "1 2\n h a\n hello"
1 2\n h a\n hello
```

You probably meant to do:

```
echo -e "1 2\n h a\n hello" | ./a.out
```

Which redirects the following to a.out:

```
1 2
 h a
 hello
```

If you don't want those extra spaces before `h a` and `hello`, remove the spaces after the `\n`'s.

The `-e` flag tells echo to convert escape sequences.